# Spring integration with Spring boot 1.4.0. Getting error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I upgraded from Spring boot 1.2.3 to 1.4.0 alongwith dependencies for Spring integration i.e. 4.3.1

I'm sending JSON content but getting an error on request submit. Previously it was working fine with Spring boot 1.2.3 and spring integration 4.1.2

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-ws</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

---

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="controller" request-channel="requestChannel" reply-channel="responseChannel" path="/services/test" 
supported-methods="POST" request-payload-type="com.example.SampleRequest" >
    <int-http:request-mapping consumes="application/json" 
        produces="application/json" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

---

```
public class SampleRequest  {

    private String requestType;
    private String reference;
    private String nicNumber;

}
```

---

```
Error : 
2016-12-20 15:06:14 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.t.h.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter : Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@74518c78] at [http://localhost:8080/services/test]
2016-12-20 15:06:14 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR c.s.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap : SAAJ0537: Invalid Content-Type. Could be an error message instead of a SOAP message
2016-12-20 15:06:14 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.t.h.MessageDispatcherServlet : Could not complete request
org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?; nested exception is com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:216)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:92)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:87)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:293)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
```

---

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.SOAPExceptionImpl: Invalid Content-Type:application/json. Is this an error message instead of a SOAP response?
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.identifyContentType(MessageImpl.java:655)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.MessageImpl.<init>(MessageImpl.java:301)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl.<init>(Message1_1Impl.java:65)
at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.createMessage(SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl.java:63)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring boot `1.2.3` didn't have WebService (SOAP) support. Right now we have `WebServicesAutoConfiguration` since `1.4.0`. There you can find this code:

```
String path = this.properties.getPath();
String urlMapping = (path.endsWith("/") ? path + "*" : path + "/*");
ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet,
            urlMapping);
```

Where you bump unexpected default in the `WebServicesProperties`:

```
@NotNull
@Pattern(regexp = "/[^?#]*", message = "Path must start with /")
private String path = "/services";
```

So, that newly created `MessageDispatcherServlet` intercepts all your requests because you expect them on the `path="/services/test"`.

If you are not interested in the SOAP server side in your application you can just exclude `WebServicesAutoConfiguration` from auto-configuration.

Otherwise consider to change your service URL or specify something another for the `spring.webservices.path` application property.

Comment: But Artem, was there any specific reason of mapping it by default to /services. Also, it is not mentioned in any of the documents i checked. I tried the second approach too by chaging the service URL and it worked.

Comment: Take a look into http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties. You will find there something about web services